# How to run Esoteric Language ZOMBIE

Tags: esoteric-languages

Can anyone please tell me how can I compile and run a program written on ZOMBIE? For example, if I wrote the following source cord to print out “hello world” on to the screen, how can I make an .exe file out of it. Thanks!

```
HelloWorld is a zombie 
summon   
task SayHello
  say "Hello World!"
animate
animate
```

Comment: It runs on BRAAAAAIIINNNNNSSSSS... ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a compiler for this language. Only [an interpreter written in Python](http://esoteric.voxelperfect.net/wiki/User:Marinus/ZOMBIE_interpreter) exists.

However, since it is written in Python, you could change `Environment.__init__` from reading a file to directly embedding your source code, then [generate an exe out of it](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-can-i-create-a-stand-alone-binary-from-a-python-script).

Answer (score 0):

Since you probably use Interpreter to run the program
this language, then compiled. echo file is not likely to be done